# how to get values of the closest td using class name

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I got stuck at one point.

```
var ctyid = $("#listEmployee").closest("tr").find(".country:first").text(); // not working getting empty values

var ctyid = $("#listEmployee").find(".country:first").text(); //Wroking fine
```

In the above code `listEmployee` is table id name. This code only returns first row data. I have a button on the row, I want data on button click row.

Comment: `closest` gets the *parent* - if `#listEmployee` is the table, then you don't want `closest` to get a `tr` *inside* that table.   In the button click, use `this` to reference the button, *then* use `.closest("tr")` ie `$(".btn").click(function() { $(this).closest("tr")...`

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I am able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you create a simple `onclick` function. Whenever the user clicks on the function the `onlick` function will be hit and your following code will return all of in the present `tr`.

```
 <table>
    <td>
    <button type='submit' onclick='loadTableRowData(this)'> 
    </td>
    </table> 

      <script>
        //Your Code
        function loadTableRowData(d)
        var ctyid = $("#listEmployee").closest("tr").find(".country:first").text();
        </script>
```

I think this will be help you out

Comment: `var ctyid = $("#listEmployee")` should probably be `var ctyid = $(d)` in this code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well. create a simple function and paste the given code into it. This code will solve your issue.

> Create a function that will be on click. Whenever you click on it the function will be fired.

```
 var cityid = $("#listEmployee" + closest("td"));
 var finalResult = cityid.find(".country:first")+text();
 console.log(finalResult);
```